# how to use variable in url of a blogger script

Tags: javascript, blogger

i want to replace the blogger feed with external feed
so i made a JSON feed and warped in calling function and saved in external server
and i replaced the default feed

```
<script expr:src='data:blog.canonicalHomepageUrl + &quot;/feeds/posts/summary/?alt=json-in-script&amp;redirect=false&amp;start-index=1&amp;max-results=200&amp;callback=related_posts&quot;'/>
```

with

```
<script src="https://example.com/feed.js"></script>'
```

and it worked well, but i want to use variable in URL to change the feed between
feed1.js ..... feed4.js
so i want to add variable from 1 to 4 in the script URL
how to do that?

tried that but didn't work

```
<script expr:src='&quot;https://example.com/feed&quot; + variable + &quot;.js&quot;'/>
```

any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use JavaScript to Achieve this. You need to create `counter`, and increment the value as needed (here I am using a button). Then update the `src` of script accordingly.

```js
let script = document.querySelector("#script");
let counter = 1;

script.src = `https://example.com/feed${counter}.js`

console.log(script.src)

document.querySelector(".btn").onclick = function(){
  counter++;
  script.src = `https://example.com/feed${counter}.js`
  console.log(script.src)
}
```

```html
<script id="script" src="https://example.com/feed.js"></script>'

<button class="btn">Change</button>
```

Comment: You need to ise `if` condition to limit the counter